# Auto-detect user geolocation with Shipping charges

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce how to display different shipping charges for different countries to auto-detect user geolocation. Someone help me.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, So please do some research and share your efforts of what you have done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stack Overflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is already a part of WooCommerce core - it just requires use of MaxMind Geolocation. Information on this can be found in the docs here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/maxmind-geolocation-integration/ .

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide more details and we'll try to help best we can.